# Convert 'numpy.ndarray' to float64 failed in python?

Tags: python

This is my code below:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([[2,2,2]])
x = np.dot(b,a.T)
print(type(x))
```

This give me `'numpy.ndarray'`,I want to convert `'numpy.ndarray'` to float64:

```
x = x.astype(np.float64)
print(type(x))
```

but it returned `'numpy.ndarray'`, why doesn't work?

Comment: But `x` is a 3x3 matrix. How would you convert that to a float? `astype` converts the *elements* of the matrix.

Comment: if i got a 1x1 'numpy.ndarray' , how can i convert it to float64?

Comment: see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: you probably want to use **`float(np.dot(a,b.T))`**.

Your `np.dot` generates a 3×3 matrix:

```
>>> np.dot(a.T,b)
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [6, 6, 6]])
```

And there is no universal inherent way to convert a matrix to a float (you can of course calculate for instance the *determinant*, but that is *a* conversion).

You probably want to use the `np.dot` the other way around:

```
>>> np.dot(a,b.T)
array([[12]])
```

Now it is a 1×1 matrix. Here it is of course reasonable to simply pop the element out of the matrix. We can do this through *indexing*:

```
>>> np.dot(a,b.T)[0,0]
12
>>> type(np.dot(a,b.T)[0,0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

So now we obtained the single `in64` element. This is still not a float, but now we can use the `float` constructor of Python to obtain a float:

```
>>> float(np.dot(a,b.T)[0,0])
12.0
>>> type(float(np.dot(a,b.T)[0,0]))
<class 'float'>
```

Now the best part is that in case the matrix contains only a single element, numpy makes it more convenient, and you can simply **call `float(..)` on the matrix**. So:

```
>>> float(np.dot(a,b.T))
12.0
```

In case you want to use a **`np.float64`**, it is more or less the same:

```
>>> np.float64(np.dot(a,b.T))
12.0
>>> type(np.float64(np.dot(a,b.T)))
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: Probably worth adding that the Numpy way of doing this would be to  use the inbuilt function `item`. Just doing : `np.dot(b,a.T).item()` would return `12`, although if float is really desired, call `np.float54` is more suited.